# How read Gmail via POP3 with ActivePerl 5.10 on Windows XP?

Tags: perl, email, windows-xp, gmail, pop3

I'm using Windows XP SP3 with ActiveState Perl 5.10.0, and I've written this function--taken/edited from CPAN's Net::POP3--in an attempt to read Gmail via POP3:

```
  my $pop = Net::POP3->new('pop.gmail.com', 
                            Timeout => 60, 
                            Port => 995, 
                            Debug => 1) || die "$!";
  my $num = $pop->login('xyz@gmail.com', 'password');
  if (!defined($num))
  {
    die "Error: couldn't sign-in to your email account.\n";
  }
  elsif ($num > 0)
  {
    warn "There are $num message(s) in your inbox.\n";
    my $msgnums = $pop->list;
    foreach my $msgnum (keys %$msgnums)
    {
      my $msg = $pop->get($msgnum);
      print @$msg;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    die "There are no messages in your inbox. (Nothing to do.)\n"
  }

  $pop->quit;
```

The code simply times-out with this error message:

```
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at C:/Perl/lib/Net/POP3.pm line 59.
Bad file descriptor at pop3.pl line xxx (i.e., the Net::POP3->new() line)
```

The debug info from Net::POP3 before the timeout occurred was:

```
Net::POP3>>> Net::POP3(2.29)
Net::POP3>>>   Net::Cmd(2.29)
Net::POP3>>>     Exporter(5.62)
Net::POP3>>>   IO::Socket::INET(1.31)
Net::POP3>>>     IO::Socket(1.30_01)
Net::POP3>>>       IO::Handle(1.27)
Net::POP3=GLOB(0x20d253c): Timeout at pop3.pl line xxx
```

I also tried using `Mail::POP3Client`; no joy on Windows XP because neither CPAN nor PPM would install it and its dependencies (`IO::SOCKET::SSL` and etc.).

Any ideas what's wrong with my code and/or how one can read Gmail via POP3 on Windows XP with ActivePerl 5.10.0?

According to Gmail, the standard configuration instructions are:

```
Incoming Mail (POP3) Server - requires SSL:  pop.gmail.com
Use SSL: Yes
Port: 995
```

Comment: "Bad file descriptor" is a common value for `$!`, and nothing I see makes me think `$!` is meaningful there. One of its base classes stores messages in `$@`, so that might actually be meaningful.

Comment: That said, that usage of Net::POP3 is not going to work since SSL is required.

Comment: Re: SSL: I also tried Net::POP3::SSLWrapper but, like Mail::POP3Client & etc., it would not install (neither cpan nor ppm).

Comment: IO::Socket::SSL isn't available from ppm because a random number generator must be installed first. See its README. Oddly, I have it installed. I think it might actually have come bundled with ActivePerl itself. (Newer version, though)

Comment: What did you do when IO::Socket::SSL's installer directed you to read its [README](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IO-Socket-SSL/README) file and tell you to install a random number generator?

Comment: Neither cpan nor ppm mentioned doing that. cpan's output of 1,817 lines makes no mention of 'random'. ppm (often useless) simply says, "Can't find any package that provides IO::Socket::SSL"

Comment: P.S. by 'cpan' I mean the command I enter at the shell prompt.

Comment: From `cpan IO::Socket::SSL`, I get `Net::SSLeay could not find a random number generator on
your system.  This will likely cause most of the tests
to fail.  Please see the README file for more information.` If you didn't get that error, what error did you get?

Comment: There were about 400+ lines of output. All 23 of 23 tests failed. No mention of the word 'random' anywhere. Again, this was with 5.10.0.

Comment: This happens far before tests are started. (In `cpan`, do `o conf build_dir_reuse 0` and `o conf commit`. You might now be skipping the steps that report the error.)

Comment: As much as I wanted to keep Perl 5.10.0, after four hours of working on this, I instead opted to upgrade to 5.16.2. I replaced 'use Net::POP3' with 'use Net::POP3::SSLWrapper', and used ppm to install it (it was successful with 5.16.2). REMEMBER TO add pop3s { }; around the original code! (See the example at CPAN.) So now it's working! Thank you, ikegami, for your assistance.

Comment: Ugh! `Net::POP3`/`Net::POP3::SSLWrapper` ended up NOT being able to read messages. I could log-in, and get a list (`$pop->list;`) of messages (hash; key = msg num, value = size), but the attempts to get (`$pop->get($msgnum);`) failed: `Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at C:/Perl/lib/Net/POP3.pm line 312` So I switched to `Mail::POP3Client` instead: IT WORKS!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SSL to access GMail. This means you need to install the Perl module `IO::Socket::SSL`. But this is very simple. ActiveState ships a good cpan client and a huge amount of binary 'PPM' packages. It does require that you upgrade Perl to 5.14 or 5.16 or get some kind of contract they require for supporting older perls.

You can also use [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com); it has an equally good cpan client + build tools.